# Comport DataReceived Visibility to Window Form

Tags: serial-port, visibility

I have been asked to write a serial-port library that handles the serial-port functionality required for an application.  The **library's method** *openComportToTuneSuite()* is called from the main Windows Form and the serial port is set up for communication, including assigning the "*portMessageReceivedFromTuneSuite*" method when the *comport.DataReceived* event is raised. Everything seems to work well; however I cannot resolve how to make the data returned from the DataReceived method ("_response" within the code below) visible to the main Window Form. Since this method is called as a result of setting up an EventHandler within the library and not the result of a specific method call from the main Windows Form (which would permit returning a response), there is no opportunity for a _response to be sent back to the application.

Could someone please steer me in the right direction as to how to make the data received from the DataReceived method visible called from the supporting library to main Window Form?

**Library Method**

```
 public string openComportToTuneSuite()
    {    
       _tuneSuiteComport.BaudRate = 19200;
       _tuneSuiteComport.DataBits = 8;
       _tuneSuiteComport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
       _tuneSuiteComport.Parity = Parity.None;
       _tuneSuiteComport.PortName = "COM11";
       _tuneSuiteComport.Handshake = Handshake.None;
       _tuneSuiteComport.RtsEnable = true;
       _tuneSuiteComport.Open();
       _tuneSuiteComport.DataReceived += portMessageReceivedFromTuneSuite;
    }


   private void portMessageReceivedFromTuneSuite(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string _response = "";
        var responseFromChronos = _tuneSuiteComport.ReadExisting();
        var responseArray = responseFromChronos.Split('\r');
        foreach (var response in responseArray)
        {
            _response = _response + response.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        //return _response;
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately my coding experience is self-taught and I am not sure how to go about raising an event to provide visibility of the _response string to the main Windows Form.  I have been researching; however Events seem to be less straight-forward than most other C# concepts I've attempted.  Is it possible that you could get me started with a coding example that would demonstrate how to recognize that a _response string is available, notify the form object of the availability and provide visibility of the string to the form?  I would certainly appreciate any further direction you could provide.

Comment: I think that I may have figured it out. I added an event ("public event ChangedEventHandler ComportDataAvailable;") to the library and code to raise the event within the portMessageReceivedFromTuneSuite procedure ("ComportDataAvailable(this, e, _response);").  Lastly I added a delegate to the Windows Form - ("public void MessageFromTuneSuiteHandler(object sender, EventArgs args, string msgToLog) { tuneSuite_Log(msgToLog); }") and added the EventHandler ("TuneSuiteInstance.ComportDataAvailable += MessageFromTuneSuiteHandler;").  It seems to work. Thank you for your guidance.